# questions related to Azure Active Directory v2.0 and the OpenID Connect protocol

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

working on project that need this, reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc
and do have a couple of questions:
1) as for single sign-out feature as mentioned in the link above, 
do you mean if like user A has 100 web applications logged in, 
if what he did is: register **LogoutUrl** and implement "session clear" for **LogoutUrl** in 20 of these 100 web applications, 
then when logout, these 20 applications signed out automatically, while the other 80 applications still sign-in?

2) for {**tenant**} required to access like /authorize, /token endpoint in the link above, do you mean all users can just use 'common',
or they have to specify as their own {tenant} value from AAD?
I tried to use 'common' which seems works, 
but after I switch to use my own {tenant} found in AAD portal, seems it got redirected to another strange web page and not working?
so want to know what is the actual difference of 'common' v.s. user-specific **{tenant}**?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

For question1:

When the user A register LogoutUrl and implement "session clear" for LogoutUrl in 20 of these 100 web applications, there will only 20 applications signed out if you sign them out. And if only one of these register LogoutUrl apps is signed out, it cannot sign others register LououtUrl apps out automatically.

For question2:

When 'common' or'tenant' is used needs to consider with your application(to access). 'common' is used when you configure the multi-tenant application. By this, it will allow other tenants user access your multi-tenant application. When you set your application as the single tenant application, 'tenant' will only allow the own users to access the application. For the details about the single tenant or multi-tenant app, please read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-types#single-tenant-and-multi-tenant-apps).

Comment: thanks so for Q1: what do you mean "all" here? do you mean all 100 web applications will be signed out, or just 20 of them? (suppose users have already signed in all 100 applications)

Answer (score 0):

@SunnySun

thanks a lot for the reply. for question1, still confused about your answer.
another example for this:
Suppose this is what user A has done:
1) registered LogoutUrl
2) implemented web applications App1, App2, App3, App4
3) in web application App1 and App2: implemented LogoutUrl with "session clear" 
while in App3, App4: no implementation for LogoutUrl at all
4) now user has signed in all these four applications App1-4

case#1: user signed out from App1
so what will happen? 
will user be signed out from App1, App2, App3, App4?
Or user will just be signed out from App1 and App2, while still remain signed in for App3, App4?

case#2: user signed out from App3
What will happen now?
will user be signed out from App1, App2, App3, App4?
Or user will just be signed out from App1 and App2, while still remain signed in for App3, App4?
Or user still remain signed in for App1, App2, and App4?

Comment: If you not use the LogoutUrl, after the user signing in first app, the second app will use the generated session cookie from the first app, it will not need the user to enter the credential, and this will work for others until the session invalidated. To use the LogoutUrl, when the user signs out, it will clear the session cookie, until the next time user signs in, the user will need to enter the credential again.

Comment: sorry what will be the result for the two cases above?

Comment: Case1: User will be signed out from App1, and still remain signed in for App 2, App3, and App4. Case2: User will be signed out from App3, and others will still remain signed in.